# Padlock sign on C, D and E drive

Tags: windows, encryption

[image: picture of device encryption status]

[image: picture of those padlock on the drives]

So I use Windows 11 home version. Last night I added another account on my laptop making it aslo an administrator. Then I checked This PC and and I found all my drives have the open padlock icon.

I thought removing the new account would solve the problem but those padlock signs were still there in my original account. Then I tried using system restore point but somehow after 10 minutes of screen going black I got the notification that it failed too because some files were opened of another user.

Then after watching couple of videos I found that you can remove it if you turn off device encryption then the lock sign will be removed. And it did but I don't want to turn off device encryption. As I think it was turned on before I created all this mess.

Can I ever get it back to how it was before?

Update: I took help of microsoft support agent today(20 March 2023) The agent suggested me to turn off the device encryption as it's not necessary.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144737/discussion-on-question-by-rads-padlock-sign-on-c-d-and-e-drive); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.